# OData OrderBy Syntax for Primitive Collection

Tags: odata, primitive

When querying a collection of complex objects with OData, I would reference the property name of the field to sort and optionally a direction:

`http://server/customers?$orderBy=Name desc`

What's the syntax for ordering a collection of a primitive type, such as a collection of strings?

`http://server/tags?$orderBy={WhatGoesHere} desc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the primitive with $it,
so your request should be

```
http://server/tags?$orderby=$it desc
```

as you can see here: https://issues.oasis-open.org/browse/ODATA-393
it was added in OData 4.0, if you use an older version it will probably not work